# Using igraph, how to force curvature when arrows point in opposite directions

Tags: r, plot, igraph

autocurve.edges does an amazing job of curving edges in igraph plots so that they don't overlap when they point in the same direction.  However, when they point in opposite directions, no curvature is applied.

```
d <- data.frame(start=c("a","a","b","c"),end=c("b","b","c","b"))


graph <- graph.data.frame(d, directed=T)

plot(graph,
     vertex.color="white")
```

[image: igraph with superimposed arrows pointing in opposite directions]

The issue is for the arrows between b and c (or c and b).

Other than specifying curvature manually, any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would use the `edge.curved` option with the same `seq` call that autocurve.edges uses.

```
plot(graph,
     vertex.color="white", edge.curved=seq(-0.5, 0.5, length = ecount(graph)))
```

[image]

### EDIT:

As Étienne pointed out, this solution also curves edges for unique observations. The solution is then to modify the `autocurve.edges` function. This is my modified function called `autocurve.edges2`. Basically, it generates a vector, which curves only non-unique edges.

```
autocurve.edges2 <-function (graph, start = 0.5)
{
    cm <- count.multiple(graph)
    mut <-is.mutual(graph)  #are connections mutual?
    el <- apply(get.edgelist(graph, names = FALSE), 1, paste,
        collapse = ":")
    ord <- order(el)
    res <- numeric(length(ord))
    p <- 1
    while (p <= length(res)) {
        m <- cm[ord[p]]
        mut.obs <-mut[ord[p]] #are the connections mutual for this point?
        idx <- p:(p + m - 1)
        if (m == 1 & mut.obs==FALSE) { #no mutual conn = no curve
            r <- 0
        }
        else {
            r <- seq(-start, start, length = m)
        }
        res[ord[idx]] <- r
        p <- p + m
    }
    res
}
```

And here's the result when adding a single, non-mutual edge (C->D):

```
library(igraph)
d <- data.frame(start=c("a","a","b","c","c"),end=c("b","b","c","b","d"))
graph <- graph.data.frame(d, directed=T)
curves <-autocurve.edges2(graph)
plot(graph, vertex.color="white", edge.curved=curves)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great step in the right direction! Thanks. However, this causes all edges to curve, even unique edges.

Comment: Really nice function. Thanks from me too!