# Use the `pos` argument in Rgraphviz to fix node position

Tags: r, graph, r-graphviz

Based on this question [Automatically curving an arc when it is overlapping with another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45721802/automatically-curving-an-arc-when-it-is-overlapping-with-another-one), I am trying to set the `pos` attribute in a `RGraphviz` plot.

Can someone show how to correctly use the `pos` attribute or suggest a more robust workaround. thanks.

*Example*

To be consistent with the above linked question, the following example starts from a `bnlearn` graph with nodes in a grid layout.

```
library(bnlearn)
library(Rgraphviz)
library(igraph)

# Create graph
adj <- matrix(0L, ncol = 9, nrow = 9, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:9], LETTERS[1:9]))
adj[upper.tri(adj)] <- 1
e <- empty.graph(LETTERS[1:9])
amat(e) <- adj
g <- as.graphNEL(e)

# layout in grid
ig <- igraph.from.graphNEL(g)
lay <- layout.grid(ig)
lay <- setNames(data.frame(norm_coords(lay, -100, 100, -100, 100)), c("x", "y"))
```

The help page `?GraphvizAttributes` indicates that `pos` should be set as

> Position of the node (For neato layouts, this is the initial position of the node). Specified using the notion val,val where each val is a double.

And a bit further down, for `neato` only attributes

> pin: If TRUE and node has a pos attribute on input, neato prevents the node from moving from the input position. The default for this attribute is FALSE.

I cannot find the correct way to apply this argument.

Various things I've tried with no success

```
# Passed named list with `x` and `y` positions
# To see the `pos` attribute has not been added you can use `AgNode(z)[[1]]`  
rownames(lay) <- nodes(e)
pos <- lapply(split(lay, rownames(lay)), unlist)
z <- agopen(g, "gg", nodeAttrs=list(pos=pos, 
                                    pin=setNames(rep(TRUE, length(nodes(e))), nodes(e))), 
                                    layoutType="neato")

# Passed as a named character string with coordinates pasted together
lay1 <- do.call(paste, c(lay, sep=","))
pos <- paste(lay1, '!') # also tried with `pos = paste(lay)`
names(pos) <- nodes(e)
z <- agopen(g, "gg", nodeAttrs=list(pos=pos, 
                                    pin=setNames(rep(TRUE, length(nodes(e))), nodes(e))), 
                                    layoutType="neato")
```

---

I can get the expected outcome with this workaround, but it won't be robust.

```
# write out dot file
z <- agopen(g, "gg")
agwrite(z, "so.dot")

#positions
lay1 <- do.call(paste, c(lay, sep=","))
pos <- paste('pos = "', lay1, '!"')

#read in dot
rd <- readLines("so.dot")
id <- sapply(paste0("label=", nodes(e)) , grep, rd)

#add in positions
for(i in seq(id)) {  
  rd[id[i]] <- gsub(names(id)[i], paste(names(id)[i], pos[i], sep="\n"), rd[id[i]])
  }

# output and render
cat(rd, file="so1.dot", sep="\n")
system("neato so1.dot -n -Tpdf -o so.pdf")
```

To give the expected outcome

[image]